# Printing on iOS shows yellow color in margins

Tags: ios, printing

For some reason when I use the Print Simulator, I get a weird yellow background color in the margin:[image]

I don't have a physical AirPrint printer to test it on, so I'm not sure if it's just a simulator issue or not.

Comment: For what it's worth I've just tested using the print simulator and see a yellow border too even though with a real airprint printer all is fine ...

Comment: Thanks, I tried it again in the simulator today and I don't see the yellow border. Unfortunately I don't have a real AirPrint printer to test it on, so I was curious if this was a simulator-only issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That yellow area is configurable in the printer simulator. It is controlled by the 'Show printable area' option in the printer simulator preferences.
It serves as a guide to verify the print layout, as per the docs, anything that appears in the yellow area will be clipped by an actual printer.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't look in the prefs!